# I can not let readers comment on my WordPress blog with Twenty seventeen theme

Tags: wordpress, widget, comments, blogs

I have used the widget for comments, but there is no place readers can write their comments. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In Posts and Pages, you can view enabling Comments Section at the end. 
if you cant, you can check it in the "Discussion Option" in page or overall wordpress setting